# Validation for Mobile Number with Country Code

Tags: 2013

I am using SharePoint 2013. I just entered Mobile Number in Lists Library. But the mobile number entered is not in Validated Form.

I need to add mobile number with country code i.e. `+(91)`

Please help me out Guys to make validation for Mobile Number with Country Code. i.e `+(91)xxx-xxxx-xxx`

**Example:** `+(91)987-6543-210`.

Answer (score 0):

Add content editor webpart in your new item page and add a script

```
<script language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
   $("input[title='Phone']").mask("+(99)999-9999-999");
});
</script>
```

It will validate number and only accept if number is in same format